# How can I place content in page_top in D7 since it is hidden in regions?

Tags: theming

I need to place a small menu in the page_top region using D7. I know the region is hidden, so my thought is to create a completely new region in the place that page_top would be showing up (I'm not sure how this is done). I have been creating a subtheme using Zen. Does anyone have an idea about how I can do this? Help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the .info file of your theme you can add regions.

The template files that control your page layout are going to display that region.
Usually page.tpl.php will have the regions called upon for display.  So if you add a region to the .info file you will need to add the region in the page.tpl.php file as well.

Great article here... a little dated.. but still works.
http://yuriybabenko.com/blog/creating-new-drupal-regions